# BGE Character is invisible when press play

Tags: game-engine, objects

So I am making a pretty basic game where you just collect keys to open doors. And I came across an issue. My game was working perfectly fine before and I haven't even touched my character in days. But all of a sudden I can't see the character when I press play. The mesh for the character is there but the mesh with the amateur is not.

Here is what I already tried or know.

- The normals are all okay
- It is not invisible in the render camera
- It is not invisible on the layer
- I haven't touched it at all in the past days so it is weird that it is happening in the first place
- While I am editing the game the character is there
- When I play the game first thing it just isn't there. It doesn't move fast or go anywhere that I can see
- Even if I play the game without looking through a camera it does the same thing. Or even if I look through both cameras available it still does it.
- It seems to be the only thing missing. Everything else is still there
- I have it set that the actual character is no collision. While there is a box around around it that is invisible that plays as the character (moves for it and has the collision)

Please let me know if you have had this issue or you think you might know what is wrong. 
Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: very difficult to know without reviewing the blend